# ¿Con qué valores puedo inicializar un atributo de tipo clase?

Tags: java

Buenas tardes, quiero profundizar un poco más en mi duda sobre los atributos tipo clase. Tengo dos clases:

La "Cliente":

```
`package modeloBancario;

public class Cliente {

private int idCliente;
private String nombre;
private String direccion;
private String telefono;

public Cliente (){

    idCliente = 0;
    nombre = null;
    direccion = null;
    telefono = null;

}

public Cliente (int idCliente, String nombre, String direccion, String telefono){

    this.idCliente = idCliente;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.direccion = direccion;
    this.telefono = telefono;

}`
```

y "Cuenta" (que es abstracta):

```
`package modeloBancario;

public abstract class Cuenta {

protected int numeroDeCuenta;
protected double saldo;
protected Cliente titular;

public Cuenta(){

    numeroDeCuenta = 0;
    saldo = 0;
    titular = null;

}

public Cuenta (int numeroDeCuent, double saldo, Cliente titular){

    this.numeroDeCuenta = numeroDeCuenta;
    this.saldo = saldo;
    this.titular = titular;`
```

y otra "CuentaCorriente", que es hija de "Cuenta":

```
`package modeloBancario;

public class CuentaCorriente extends Cuenta {

protected final double interesFijo = 0.0015;
protected double cantidadRetirada;

public CuentaCorriente(int numeroDeCuenta, double saldo, Cliente titular){

    super (numeroDeCuenta, saldo, titular);

}`
```

Bueno pues mi duda es a la hora de usar el constructor con parámetros de la clase "CuentaCorriente" para crear un objeto. Entiendo que en el parámetro numeroDeCuenta va un número int, en el saldo otro numero double, pero en cambio no sé que valores poner en el parametro titular:

```
`    public static void main(String[] args) {

    CuentaCorriente libreta1 = new CuentaCorriente(1,5000,¿¿¿???);`
```

He probado de todo y todo me da errores. ¿Que valor o valores se deberian de poner ahí?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En el ultimo parametro le tenes q pasar un objeto de tipo Cliente. Si no lo tenes definido lo podes crear ahi mismo haciendo:

```
Cliente cliente1 = new Cliente (<los parametros del cliente>);

CuentaCorriente libreta1 = new CuentaCorriente(1,5000,cliente1);
```

Se que se puede pasar el mismo obj por parametro sin tener q crearlo antes pero no me acuerdo la sintaxis.

Comment: a lo q me refiero en cuanto a pasarlo por parametro es:    `CuentaCorriente libreta1 = new CuentaCorriente(1,5000,new Cliente(<parametros del cliente>));
`. Pero no se si esa es la sintaxis exacta.

Comment: Osea, en ese parámetro titular puedo meter un objeto creado que venga de la clase de donde nace. Vale, entiendo, pensaba que tambien se podria hacer algo asi:

    `public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        CuentaCorriente libreta1 = new CuentaCorriente(1,5000,(<parámetros del cliente>);`

Comment: si le pasas los parametros del cliente sin anteponer el `new Cliente` no va a interpretar eso como un objeto si no como un monton de parametros por separado.

Comment: Gracias, me ha servido mucho la respuesta. Aun asi, ya puestos, seria genial que alguien nos dijera como crear el objeto en el mismo parametro para no tener que crearlo antes.

Comment: Ahi le pregunte a un amigo, es como decía yo: `objeto1 = new Objeto1(new Objeto2());`

Answer (score 0):

Debes poner los parametros que recibe la clase

un ejemplo seria asi:

Cliente cliente1 = new Cliente ("nombre", numero);